# What does var = var && "*" mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out some obfusicated code by reading it, and I was doing pretty well until a came across this:

```
a = a && "*"
```

Now I am still quite new to Javascript and these shortened uncommon javascript codes are still very foreign to me, this is the first time I have come across them.

Does anybody know what this does? I attempted it in a javascript code tester ad it just returned *, so I do not know.

Also, if anybody knows where I can look to find out what these uncommon lines of code do, that would be very helpful. They are all shortened and are sorts of things like this and

```
a = a || b
```

(I know what that one does)

But If there is some sort of name for this kind of javascript or a reference I can look at, that would be very helpful, I have been scouring Google for hours.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript) and [JavaScript. What does this expression mean: “ var a = b === c && d; ”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896453/javascript-what-does-this-expression-mean-var-a-b-c-d). It's called short-circuit evaluation, read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation

Comment: Could have been written as (i) `if (a) {a="*";}` (ii) `if (!a) {a=b;}`

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `a` is truthy, it assigns `"*"` to `a`.

If `a` is falsy, it remains untouched.

---

`&&` has short-circuit semantics: A compound expression `(e1) && (e2)`—where `e1` and `e2` are arbitrary expressions themselves—evaluates to either

- `e1` if `e1` evaluates to false in a boolean context—`e2` is ***not*** evaluated
- `e2` if `e1` evaluates to true in a boolean context

This does ***not*** imply that `e1` or `e2` and the entire expression `(e1) && (e2)` need evaluate to true or false!

In a boolean context, the following values evaluate to `false` [**as per the spec**](http://es5.github.com/x9.html#x9.2):

- null
- undefined
- ±0
- NaN
- false
- the empty string

All<sup>1</sup> other values are considered `true`.

The above values are succinctly called "falsy" and the others "truthy".

**Applied to your example**: `a = a && "*"`

According to the aforementioned rules of short-circuit evaluation for `&&`, the expression evaluates to `a` if `a` is *falsy*, which is then in turn assigned to `a`, i.e. the statement simplifies to `a = a`.

If `a` is *truthy*, however, the expression on the right-hand side evaluates to `*`, which is in turn assigned to `a`.

---

**As for your second question**: `(e1) || (e2)` has similar semantics:

The entire expression evaluates to:

- `e1` if `e1` is truthy
- `e2` if `e1` is falsy

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348995/al)</sup>

Comment: "Now I am still quite new to Javascript". As a novice JavaScript programmer, the OP might need a better explanation to understand the concept.